# Passing component and props as arguments

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to render a component in App.js based on a MobX observable value. I want to define an action that takes a component and some new custom prop assignments. Here's what I have now:

```
// App.js inside render()
{ ui_store.main_area_sequence }
```

.

```
// ui_store.js

// OBSERVABLES / state
main_area_sequence = <ChoosePostType />;

// ACTIONS / state mutators
update_ui_in_main_section(ComponentTag, props) {
    this.main_area_sequence = <ComponentTag {props} />
}
```

The component argument works as intended. But I can't get the props argument working. Ideally I would use it to build something like:

```
<ChildComponentToBeSwitchedIn name={ui_store.name} handleClick={this.handleClick} />
```

A button in `<ChoosePostType />` might reassign the observable value in `main_area_sequence` to the above on click, as one example.

Does anyone know how to pass prop assignments as an argument in order to do this?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). You've described the solution you want to implement, but not the actual problem you're trying to solve. I suggest editing your question to include a description of what your broader goal is.

Comment: Ok then, I have updated the post with my intent. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: "My intention is that I want to be able to use this function to return a component and some new custom props." Okay, but why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My current project will render new child components based on the state of an observable value. MobX actions are used to update observables. A solution would allow an action to update an observable to a value that has a component and newly defined custom props.

Comment: We need to see more code to understand what you're trying to accomplish. You're trying to do something with MobX, so you need to include the relevant MobX code in your question. Where are you updating the observable? Where are you consuming it? An [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be ideal.

Comment: Ok then, I have rewritten the question and code sample to show more intent and include my use case with MobX. I hope the problem is more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're overthinking this.

Recall that JSX is just JavaScript. When you type this:

```
<Foo bar={123}>Baz!</Foo>
```

...you're really writing this:

```
React.createElement(Foo, { bar: 123 }, 'Baz!');
```

What if the component you want to render is dynamic, though? That's fine; it still works. For example, suppose we kept the component and props in our React component's `state`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <this.state.dynamicComponent
      {...this.state.dynamicComponentProps}
      name={this.props.name}
      onClick={this.handleClick}
    />
  );
}
```

The above JSX translates to this JavaScript:

```
React.createElement(this.state.dynamicComponent,
  { ...this.state.dynamicComponentProps,
    name: this.props.name,
    onClick: this.handleClick,
  }
);
```

As you can see, we get props from `this.state.dynamicComponentProps`, but we also add a `name` prop from `this.props.name` and an `onClick` prop from `this.handleClick`. You can imagine `this.handleClick` calling `this.setState` to update `dynamicComponent` and `dynamicComponentProps`.

Actually, you don't have to imagine it, because you can see it working in the below snippet:

```js
class DynamicComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dynamicComponent: ShowMeFirst,
      dynamicComponentProps: { style: { color: 'blue' }},
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <this.state.dynamicComponent
        {...this.state.dynamicComponentProps}
        name={this.props.name}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      />
    );
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    this.updateDynamicComponent(ShowMeSecond, { style: { color: 'red' }});
  }

  updateDynamicComponent(component, props) {
    this.setState({
      dynamicComponent: component,
      dynamicComponentProps: props,
    });
  }
}

const ShowMeFirst = ({ name, style, onClick }) => (
  <button type="button" style={style} onClick={onClick}>
    Hello, {name}!
  </button>
);

const ShowMeSecond = ({ name, style, onClick }) => (
  <button type="button" style={style} onClick={onClick}>
    Goodbye, {name}!
  </button>
);

ReactDOM.render(<DynamicComponent name="Alice"/>, document.querySelector('div'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

I've used plain old React state above, but the same thing works with MobX, as you can see below. (I've never used MobX before, so my code might be less than idiomatic, but hopefully you'll get the idea.)

```js
const { action, decorate, observable } = mobx;
const { observer } = mobxReact;

class UIStore {
  dynamicComponent = ShowMeFirst;
  dynamicComponentProps = { style: { color: 'blue' }};
  
  updateDynamicComponent(component, props) {
    this.dynamicComponent = component;
    this.dynamicComponentProps = props;
  }
}

decorate(UIStore, {
  dynamicComponent: observable,
  dynamicComponentProps: observable,
  updateDynamicComponent: action,
});

const DynamicComponent = observer(({ store, name }) => (
  <store.dynamicComponent
    {...store.dynamicComponentProps}
    name={name}
    onClick={() =>
      store.updateDynamicComponent(ShowMeSecond, { style: { color: 'red' }})
    }
  />
));

const ShowMeFirst = ({ name, style, onClick }) => (
  <button type="button" style={{...style}} onClick={onClick}>
    Hello, {name}!
  </button>
);

const ShowMeSecond = ({ name, style, onClick }) => (
  <button type="button" style={{...style}} onClick={onClick}>
    Goodbye, {name}!
  </button>
);

ReactDOM.render(<DynamicComponent name="Alice" store={new UIStore()} />, document.querySelector('div'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mobx/lib/mobx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mobx-react@5.2.3/index.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

I had to use `decorate` here since Stack Overflow's Babel configuration doesn't include decorators, but I've posted the same thing with decorators on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/qlno63zkw4

Comment: Great answer, this clarifies everything for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't passing props, then don't include a props parameter.

```
update_ui_in_main_section(ComponentTag) {
  this.main_area_sequence = <ComponentTag handleClick={this.handleClick} />;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I do need a parameter for the prop definition though because handleClick was just one example of a prop I might define here.

Is it possible to pass a string argument and convert it to JSX? I am looking for a function to do that, but not finding anything.

Comment: Do you have an example string that you would like to pass and have it convert to props? A problem with a string that contains something like `this.handleClick` is that you cannot safely, easily, or efficiently parse what `this.handleClick` means, since it is a variable. I can't see a scenario where `this.handleClick` would be in a string instead of an object.

Comment: chooseColor=this.chooseColor. Or: status=this.state.status. I see what you mean regarding trying to pass these as strings. I'll try passing them as an object.